# using comet iframe with jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, comet

I haven't found any good tutorial with code examples on how to use comet with jquery.

found this link: http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start but they are using prototype.

and I found a comet plugin for jquery on the jquery website but there is no documentation and I can't figure out how to use it.

are there any good tutorials with concrete code examples out there teaching one to use comet iframe with jquery and php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cool link is here: [Comet and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136012/comet-and-jquery/3606772#3606772)

Nginx with the NHPM module + jQuery + PHP