# jquery comet long polling and streaming tutorials?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, comet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comet and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136012/comet-and-jquery)

im so tired of not finding good tutorials on long polling/streaming comet techniques with jquery. what is wrong with the comet community. a lot of people wanna use this but there are no good tutorials about it.

why so slow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a question about the comet community, it's just that this is only half of the problem. You eventually need a comet client (such as jquery, dojo, or custom clients according to the server), but first you need a comet server to connect to (such as Jetty, [WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync), etc). Once you pick the server, you can then pick the client. If it's a Beayux client (such as the two servers mentioned) which is an open spec, then you can just plug in any client that supports that standard.

Comment: but shouldn´t it be some more tutorials on this issue. looks like there are just a handful of them out there and very undescriptive.

Comment: There are lots of tutorials, it's just that they all start with the server. For example, there are a ton here: http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/support/tutorials, but you have to have picked WebSync before those tutorials are of any use.