# Live stream 'push' with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, client-server, cappuccino

I just found an interesting demo of what can be done with the cappuccino framework;

[Push with Cappuccino and Tornado](http://cappuccino.org/discuss/2009/10/05/push-with-cappuccino-and-tornado/)

As far as I understands it, It keeps an async client/server connection, which is great to keep a "content" updated.

I would like to know if there is any way I can do the same thing using JQuery or another library. Cappuccino looks a bit like a all-or-nothing framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing there is not particular to cappucino or Tornado: its an example of HTTP long-polling to simulate async connections.  Essentailly a client makes a request to the server with a very long (or infinite) timeout and the server responds when it has some data.

It's a workaround for the fact that until [very recently](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/) there was no way for a browser to receive a request from a web-server.  This is changing as the most recent web-standards are gaining adoption.

In short, there is nothing to stop you employing this kind of technique in any framework.  Take a look at the [wikipedia page on Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)) for more info.

In your specific case, you might find the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136012/comet-and-jquery) helpful as they are specific to jQuery.