# JQuery Div update on database update

Tags: jquery, html, refresh

Right now I am using setInterval to refresh a div every few seconds.  The page it is refreshing is data being pulled from a database in asp.  I would like to have it only refresh the div when a change occurs in the database because the query is pretty large, but I've searched and could not find function or example for this.  I figure the best way is to compare a session variable against the database, but I don't know how it can check that constantly, and then update the div when it changes.

Comment: I think I might be able to do it by using cookies.  I can have a small script checking the database constantly for a change in the field and comparing it with a cookie, which is also being monitored by the jquery cookie plugin.  If the data changes, the cookie is updated, telling jquery to refresh the div.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You might look into comet.  Let your server tell the client what it needs instead of the client polling the server. http://ajaxian.com/archives/comet-a-new-approach-to-ajax-applications [Comet and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136012/comet-and-jquery)

Even if you didn't do comet, though, it seems the solution you provided in your own question would work.  You just need to poll the server occasionally with a timestamp of the last polling, have it check a database timestamp to see if things have changed, and if so, respond accordingly, telling the client to go ahead and refresh the div.

Comment: I was able to get it going by using getJSON and pointing it to a dynamic file that checked the database with small script.  Comet looks interesting, I will have to give it a try.