# How to refresh a inbox when a new message is coming.(Like Gmail)

Tags: php, jquery, email

In my application I have an inbox. If a new message arrives I need to increment the unread count. Do I need to make the database connection for every second to find out if a new message has arrived? Are there any other methods?

Answer (score 4):

Use [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29), and load the changes when new mail comes in.

Answer (score 2):

Comet is the name given to various types of "server-push" methods that can be used to do what you are looking for. The most compatible of the comet methods is XHR Long Polling.

If you want to try out a specific comet tool, check out [jquery comet](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Comet), which was developed by [a SO member](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22474/morgan-arr-allen). He discusses his plugin at [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136012/comet-and-jquery).