# how to use jQuery ajax calls with node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, node.js

This is similar to [Stream data with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558606/stream-data-with-node-js), but I don't feel that question was answered sufficiently.

I'm trying to use a jQuery ajax call (get, load, getJSON) to transfer data between a page and a node.js server. I can hit the address from my browser and see 'Hello World!", but when I try this from my page, it fails and shows that I get no response back. I setup a simple test page and hello world example to test this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>get test</title> 
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Get Test</h1>
    <div id="test"></div>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            //alert($('h1').length);
            $('#test').load('http://192.168.1.103:8124/');
            //$.get('http://192.168.1.103:8124/', function(data) {                
            //  alert(data);
            //});
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    console.log('request received');
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8124);
```

Comment: We need to know what is in the file you are loading - how is the code in the loaded file being executed?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

If your simple test page is located on other protocol/domain/port than your hello world node.js example you are doing cross-domain requests and violating [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) therefore your jQuery ajax calls (get and load) are failing silently. To get this working cross-domain you should use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) based format. For example node.js code:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    console.log('request received');
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('_testcb(\'{"message": "Hello world!"}\')');
}).listen(8124);
```

and client side JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://192.168.1.103:8124/',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: "_testcb",
        cache: false,
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#test").append(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('error ' + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

There are also other ways how to get this working, for example by setting up [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) or build your web application entirely with framework like [express](http://expressjs.com/).

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I set this up to use jsonp, as outlined in your example, and it's working perfectly.

Comment: great answer yojimbo, this really helped me out.  I have posted an answer with some extra stuff.

Comment: how building nodejs application with express will solve the cross domain request problem ?

Comment: @runrunforest: if the application is entirely build on top of express, then you probably wouldn't need to make cross domain requests since everything will be served from the same origin.

Comment: Can Node.js run in "long polling" mode? I mean, constantly asking data from MySQL, while not receiving any continue the poll loop and when data is received increment the requested id to start a new "long poll" ??? Is this possible?

Comment: @Petsoukos Long polling (as a web based push technology) is possible in node.js through several modules (such as socket.io which also supports other transports), however polling MySQL directly would be highly inefficient. I would recommend to look at some pub/sub mechanism, for example the redis one which can be used for this purpose.

Comment: Hi yojimbo, your code is working fine in all browsers but when i am using same code for my android phonegap app it shows timeout, and always going to error: not in success , can you please suggest what may be the problem.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Rahul: Hi, unfortunately I have no experience with phonegap so you should ask someone who is knowledgeable in this technology.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to yojimbo for his answer.  To add to his sample, I wanted to use the jquery method $.getJSON  which puts a random callback in the query string so I also wanted to parse that out in the Node.js.  I also wanted to pass an object back and use the stringify function.

This is my Client Side code.

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:8124/dummy?action=dostuff&callback=?",
function(data){
  alert(data);
},
function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('error ' + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
});
```

This is my Server side Node.js

```
var http = require('http');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var url = require('url');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    //grab the callback from the query string   
    var pquery = querystring.parse(url.parse(req.url).query);   
    var callback = (pquery.callback ? pquery.callback : '');

    //we probably want to send an object back in response to the request
    var returnObject = {message: "Hello World!"};
    var returnObjectString = JSON.stringify(returnObject);

    //push back the response including the callback shenanigans
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end(callback + '(\'' + returnObjectString + '\')');
}).listen(8124);
```

Comment: Your code works great. Note that you'll get a mime error with text/plain as content type. Changing content-type to application/javascript solves that.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose your html page is hosted on a different port. Same origin policy [requires](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules) in most browsers that the loaded file be on the same port than the loading file.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like the following on the server side:

```
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    if (request.headers['x-requested-with'] == 'XMLHttpRequest') {
        // handle async request
        var u = url.parse(request.url, true); //not needed

        response.writeHead(200, {'content-type':'text/json'})
        response.end(JSON.stringify(some_array.slice(1, 10))) //send elements 1 to 10
    } else {
        // handle sync request (by server index.html)
        if (request.url == '/') {
            response.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html'})
            util.pump(fs.createReadStream('index.html'), response)
        } 
        else 
        {
            // 404 error
        }
    }
}).listen(31337)
```