# Inserting and Fetching values from mongodb using nodejs and chartjs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, chart.js, angular-cli

I am new to MEAN stack development. I have created a couple of charts using chartJS and i am able to give static values.

How can I get the values in the chart dynamically from MongoDB collections using Express.

I have separated front-end and back-end in two separate folders.

**Chart Image**

[image]

Comment: did you got that?can you share the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this problem: -

1. **Send data from your NodeJS backend while rendering the concerned HTML (with your Chart on it)** --

   - So, setup a MongoDB Instance on [mLab](https://mlab.com/) or [Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas). Then refer to any reference on how to use either [MongoDB Client](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_create_db.asp) or [Mongoose](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/mongoose) to connect to your MongoDB Database. Personally I recommend using **Mongoose**.
   - Next, in a route (let's say the home route), connect to your database and get the data you need for your chart.
     So, assuming you used [express-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-generator), add something like this in your **app.js**

     ```
     mongoose.connect(<your-mongodb-connection-string-here>,function(err) 
     {
        if (err) {
           console.log(err);
        } else {
           console.log('Database ready to use.');
        }
     });
     ```
   - Then you'll need to add your database schema to a models folder, and export it so that you can access the db from your routes. Instructions [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-mongoosejs-in-node-js-and-mongodb-applications#sample-model-for-users)
   - And in your **index.js** put something along these lines: -

     ```
     var participant = require('../models/participants.js'); //Replace participant with the name of your created model

     router.get('/home', function(req, res, next) {

          participant.find({ username: 'starlord55' }, function(err, data) {
             if (err) throw err;
             //Write processing to extract the data that you need for your chart

             res.render('<name-of-your-view(ejs,jade)>',{chartData:data})
           });
     });
     ```
   - Now (assuming your view is ejs) the chartData object is accessible from your ejs file simply like this: -

     ```
     var data = [<%= chartData %>];
     ```

     Now, add this data to your chart while initialising the chart object.
2. **Using AJAX/Angular requests to fetch the data**

   A lot of the same steps are involved, except that the data will not be sent at the `res.render` command. Instead, once the page is loaded, an AJAX request is used to request the data. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5486244/9886050). And once you get the data, add it to your chart in the same way.

Comment: Thanks for providing the solution. I am unable to find where and how to place the solution in the application.

Comment: I am using MongoDB Compass and view as hbs not ejs