# How can I establish a long-lived connection with jQuery for push notification?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to establish a long lived connection using jQuery. I have a URL in the form of:

```
http://www.sample.com/Notify?sessionId=xxxxxx
```

Now if I call this URL with the sessionId, it is equivalent to registering for Asynchronous notifications. I am aware of ajax calls using jQuery but as I understand it, after getting some data, jQuery terminates the connection. Is there a way to make it retain the connection so that the server miht be able to push information?

Comment: Maybe using WebSockets? http://code.google.com/p/jquery-websocket/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136012/comet-and-jquery) post - Bayeux / Comet with jquery