# Notify server to client via Web service

Tags: web-services

I made a WebService chat. At the client side I am running a thread to check periodically if there any new messages available.

I want to know is there are any way to notify clients via Web Service.

I found something call 'Solicit Response' related to web service. But I am not aware how it works.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In web services, the clients strictly request, they don't listen. What you need is some way for the server to "push" to the client. You're looking for something like [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) which isn't part of a web service per se.

**Edit**

Here's a relevant [stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136012/comet-and-jquery).

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. As I know XMLHttpRequest(AJAX) can only used in web. My client is a forms application like gtalk/yahoo/msn. Actually is periodically checking for new message, that real way of working chat applications. I mean is it the way that famous gtalk also working ?

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. I don't know for sure, but I doubt other forms applications using "polling" (periodically checking for new messages). Usually chats are inactive so polling is inefficient. I imagine they open up a port and use "events" (waiting passively for messages). I'm not sure though.