# Adding a Notification System to my website

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, notifications

I have developed a website, which is similar to LinkedIn and Facebook, where people join up, have a profile, can comment on things and like things etc.

I would like to add a notification system to the top like LinkedIn and Facebook where if you are logged in and someone likes something of yours you get a notification, if someone comments on something of yours you get a notification and so on. This would preferably appear as a little icon at the top displaying the number of notifications and on hovering or clicking, a panel will display with what the notification is exactly.

Does anyone know of an easy way to do this, either roughly talk em through this or pseudo code. Even better if anyone knows any AJAX or JQuery systems out there that I can incorporate into my site?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086380/how-does-facebook-gmail-send-the-real-time-notification) it might give you some idea

Comment: This may also help; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864501/how-does-one-do-realtime-updates-of-a-web-page

Comment: You can take a look at [https://notiflare.io](https://notiflare.io?utm_source=stack_overflow&utm_campaign=adding-a-notification-system-to-my-website) It's a ready to use notification system. You can deploy Notiflare in minutes and get a strong notification system. It provides a web widget and also alert users by email if there are offline. Hope that helps :D