# Implementing comet on the client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, comet

I'm trying to implement comet in my application and, being inexperienced with JavaScript, I'm not sure how to do the client side.

When the server receives a request, it just keeps it open and writes data to it when necessary:

```
def render_GET(self, request):
    print "connected"
    request.write("Initiated\r\n")
    reactor.callLater(random.randint(2, 10), self._delay, request)
    return NOT_DONE_YET;

def _delay(self, request):
    print "output"
    self.count += 1
    request.write("Hello... {0}\r\n".format(self.count))
    reactor.callLater(random.randint(2, 10), self._delay, request)
```

I've been using jQuery on the client side so far, but I can't figure out how to make it work with the server. [I've been looking at the jQuery.AJAX documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and none of the callbacks say "Hey! I just received some data!", they only say "The request is finished."

I thought the `dataFilter()` function was what I wanted since it lets you handle the raw data before the request finishes, but it only lets you do it *just* before the request finishes, and not as you receive data.

So how can I receive data continuously through an open request? As you can see in the python example, each piece of data is delimited with `\r\n` so I want the JavaScript to behave like a line receiver. Is this possible with jQuery or do I have to play with XMLHttpRequest/ActiveXObject directly? Is there a (simple, lightweight) library available which implements a line receiver for me?

I'm hoping to hear about an existing library *and* how to implement this myself, since I've had bad bad luck with comet libraries so far, and at this point I'm hoping to just write the code I need and not bother with an entire library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at some other Comet/jQuery questions, I stumbled across this: http://code.google.com/p/jquerycomet/, which looks to be a jQuery plugin that does what you're after. If you're looking to see how it works, I'd just dig into the source.

The question where I found some great information is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136012/comet-and-jquery).

Comment: The project looks completely dead now.

Answer (score 2):

A standard technique is to do a long polling request via AJAX (standard call with a really long timeout), then when receiving a response have your callback initiate another long poll when it is invoked.   If the timeout expires, then you reissue the request using the error handling mechanism.  Rather than having a single long request that periodically does something (like the "infinite iframe" technique), this uses a series of long requests to get data as the server has it available.

```
 function longPoll( url, data, cb )
 {
       $.ajax({
          url: url,
          data: data,
          timeout: Number.MAX_VALUE,
          ...other options...
          success: function(result) {
               // maybe update the data?
               longPoll( url, data, cb );
               cb.call(this,result);
          },
          error: function() {
               longPoll( url, data, cb );
          }
       }
 }
```

Comment: I've actually tried this method but I was hoping to be able to just write data to the transport rather than re-initiating so many requests. It would make it so much easier to just pass an object around than it would to re-receive a request, re-authenticate it, re-add it to a list, etc.

Comment: @tvanfosson Can you elaborate on the usefulness of this method? I do not see any benefits of this solution compared to the "infinite iframe" technique.

Answer (score 0):

this code is the simpliest I have ever seen.

```
var previous_response_length = 0
  , xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:7379/SUBSCRIBE/hello", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = checkData;
xhr.send(null);

function checkData() {
  if(xhr.readyState == 3) {
    response = xhr.responseText;
    chunk = response.slice(previous_response_length);
    previous_response_length = response.length;
    console.log(chunk);
  }
};
```