# How do sites like Swoopo or Quibids keep the timer with all gamers

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I am always curious how different sites function.

I am assuming the site in general can be built purely in PHP and javascript and that the timer is basically running on an ajax call but how does the internal server/client machine keep everybody's computers in sync at the same time (especially given JS is a client-side language)?

If it is in fact making ajax calls (apparently every 1/5 of a second) in order to keep up with the bidding/timer settings, what type of hardware and bandwidth does a site like that have to maintain?

Are there better languages for sites like these in reality?

Thanks ahead of time!

### Update

I am not asking how to create a display of a countdown in JS ultimately - how does the relay back and forth take place between the two (server and end user)

Comment: see my comment after the code below.

Comment: let me know if you need any more help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use the server's time and then output it to the client.

wherein the javascript then decrements it the same on each client.

This is **no** hit on the server. the decrement is on the client side, not on the server, as in it is **not an ajax call**.

for example:

```
var serverTime = getServerTime();

setTimeout(function(){serverTime--;},1000); 
//decrement by one every 1000 milliseconds (1 second)
```

And on each of those sites there could be a Comet (or any other long polling) in the background that when there is a change, the `getServerTime()` is called again.

This is not much of a hit on the server, like for example with Comet programming it is a hidden iframe that would call js scripts when they are needed.

see here:

[Comet and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136012/comet-and-jquery/3606772)

Comment: maniator - that was my assumption but even still, the relay between server time and having the ajax call over and over and over (there are no push notifications on a site) must be incredible, no?

Comment: see my amendment to the answer

Comment: maniator - there has to be a server relay when a bid is placed in which each bidder's counter is reset to a predetermined value

Comment: that would be set somewhere in the `getServerTime()` function in the example above.