# Bayaux protocol implementation for Jquery

Tags: jquery, comet, javascript-framework, cometd, bayeux

We have an application running on jQuery. In this, there is requirement of implementing **Bayaux protocol**. But AFAIK, only **DOJO** has implemented the Bayaux protocol in the form of **cometd**.

As we are fully dependent on jQuery, we can not import whole *dojo toolkit release* just for this implementation.

My question is - 
  Is there any implementation of Bayaux(cometd) for Jquery ?
 
  If not, Is there any micro framework which provides this implementation?
 
  If not, can I extract ony Bayaux related stuff from Dojo toolkit and exclude everything else?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this question has been answered before:   [Comet and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136012/comet-and-jquery)

http://cometd.org/documentation/cometd-javascript (references jquery/jquery.cometd.js)
http://cometd.org/documentation/howtos/primer

The jquery plugin exists in the tutorial above.