# Server-side notification Phonegap reverse ajax

Tags: java, html, cordova, websocket, comet

I'm writing a Java EE application on WebShere where I want to notify client mobile users. I'm using Phonegap and HTML5. I'm searching for a solution to notify clients. I was not able to run a websocket with Websphere and Jetty.

Is there any solution to notify mobile clients using Comet, reverse Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

I think you already know your solution. You mentioned Reverse Ajax and Comet. What you want is called long-polling or push technology.  This may get you started:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-cometjava/

[Comet and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136012/comet-and-jquery)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology

Comment: thank you for your help but I was searching an example to use in my application im using websphere ,how can I use comet with websphere?
thx again

Comment: my apologies, it looked like your question concerned the client-side implementation. I suggest you reword your summary and question to pin-point your exact question. Also, I added a link to my answer for IBM WebSphere and Comet.